# How to set model attribute to current date format using MySQL functions?

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model `Users` And every time user logges in `loggedin_at` field is updated.

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->token = md5(time());
$user->loggedin_at = date('Y-d-m H:i:s');
$user->save();

return $user;
```

But I know from experience already that sometimes there is difference between MySQL time and PHP time. So when you use comparisons like `time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR` it might now work correctly because you set date from PHP and compare it from MySQL.

Anyway my question is I want to use `NOW()` to update my date. I try

```
$user->loggedin_at = DB::raw('NOW()');
```

But that does not work. By looking into Eloquent source I've managed out this to work

```
$user->loggedin_at = new \Carbon\Carbon();
```

This is what Eloquent uses to alter times.

1. How to use `NOW()` to set time?
2. Should I use `NOW()` or better continue with Carbon?

Comment: I think it is better to use Carbon.

Comment: Thank you, very appreciate your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use Carbon, it's what it's there for. Laravel uses it out of the box, and uses it within created_at and updated_at.

If you use Carbon, also, you can synchronize PHP's time and Carbon's "NOW" using the timezone configuration inside of config/app.php.

Furthermore, if you want to change the result you get from Carbon, you can do something like:

```
$now = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

//can also be passed as a string
$now = Carbon::now('Europe/London');
```